# On checkout Paytm showing error: This MID is not available on our staging environment

Tags: laravel-5, paytm

I have integrating Paytm gateway in my site which is Laravel 5.2 version.
Everything is fine from the code side.

I have created a Paytm account and verified it. I have switched on TEST mode and I've got key and ID from *Test API Deatils* and passed in parameters as given below:

---

```
$paramList["MID"] = 'Test Merchant ID';
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $order_id;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $order_id;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = 'Retail';
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = 'WEB';
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $amount;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = 'WEBSTAGING';
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = url( 'order/paytm-callback' );
$paytm_merchant_key = 'Test Account Secret Key';
```

---

On checkout it redirects to this [website](https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction) and shows the following error:

```
MID

invalid: This MID is not available on our staging environment
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue by contacting Paytm Dev support. Some Configurations are done at their end on my given MID.

Comment: good you are sharing your experience but I think it would be good to contact first before posting question there since it saves your time.